# Issue executing chained commands with ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, cmd, process, msbuild

I have this code for executing a command line process:

```
public ProcessResult ExecuteCommand(string command, string startdir, string arguments = "")
{
    ProcessResult result = new ProcessResult();

    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = arguments,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        WorkingDirectory = startdir,
        Verb = "runas",
        FileName = command
    };

    // Redirect the output
    using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
    {
        process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            result.StandardOutput.Add(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        };
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            result.StandardError.Add(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        };
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();

        result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to start the Developer Command Prompt and execute an msbuild command but I'm having some trouble. On the command line, this works without issue:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & msbuild
> C:\Users\Documents\Development\Automation.AutoIVU\AutoIVU\AutoIVU\AutoIVU.csproj
> /p:ConfigurationPtforms=Release /p:Platform="X64"

But it fails when I execute the same in code:

```
string vsBuildConsole = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat";

string autoIVUProjPath = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Development\\Automation.AutoIVU\\AutoIVU\\AutoIVU\\AutoIVU.csproj";

string msBuildCommand = $"msbuild \"{autoIVUProjPath}\" /t:Build /p:ConfigurationPlatforms=Release /p:Platform = \"X64\"";

ProcessResult result = this.ExecuteCommand("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", ".", $"/C \"{vsBuildConsole}\" & {msBuildCommand}");
```

Command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Arguments:

> /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & msbuild
> "C:\Users\Documents\Development\Automation.AutoIVU\AutoIVU\AutoIVU\AutoIVU.csproj"
> /t:Build /p:ConfigurationPlatforms=Release /p:Platform = "X64"

Output:

`"'C:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."`

Comment: It looks like you're not actually enclosing the path in quotes like you think you are. Seeing the code where you assign the `arguments` would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated with more info @itsme86